# How can I multiply columns from different DataFrame? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to make new a DataFrame by myltiplying 'Wage' of df1 with respective value of df2 (male by male's value and female by female's value) of data2. I tried with grouping but I was unable to solve this.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'gender':['male', 'female', 'male', 'male'],
    'Age':[20, 20, 19, 19],
    'Wage': [1200, 1300, 1250, 1300]}

data2 = {'male': [0.12],
     'female': [0.13]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I wanna built new_df as:

```
new_data = {'gender':['male', 'female', 'male', 'male'],
'Age':[20, 20, 19, 19],
'New_Wage':[1200*0.12, 1300*0.13, 1250*0.12, 1300*0.12]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

Thank You !!

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) then [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html#pandas-series-mul) on level=0 with the [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) of df2.

Then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) + [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename) the column:

```
df3 = df1.set_index(['gender', 'Age'])
df3['Wage'] = df3['Wage'].mul(df2.T[0], level=0)
df3 = df3.reset_index().rename(columns={'Wage': 'New_Wage'})
```

`df3`:

```
   gender  Age  New_Wage
0    male   20     144.0
1  female   20     169.0
2    male   19     150.0
3    male   19     156.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```py
out = df1.merge(df2.T, left_on="gender", right_index=True)
out["Wage"] *= out[0]
out = out.drop(columns=0).sort_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   gender  Age   Wage
0    male   20  144.0
1  female   20  169.0
2    male   19  150.0
3    male   19  156.0
```